# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in node-ssdp

Tags: node.js, angular, asp.net-core, ssdp

After installing rokujs via npm, Can't seem to get past this error:
The package is installed correctly.
No other errors reported.

Any ideas?

```
ERROR in ./~/node-ssdp/lib/index.js
        Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'dgram' in 'C:\VisualStudio\Repos\App\App.PWA\node_modules\node-ssdp\lib'
         @ ./~/node-ssdp/lib/index.js 3:12-28
         @ ./~/node-ssdp ^.*index$
         @ ./~/node-ssdp/index.js
         @ ./~/rokujs/lib/roku.js
         @ ./~/rokujs/index.js
         @ ./ClientApp/app/components/home/home.component.ts
         @ ./ClientApp/app/app.shared.module.ts
         @ ./ClientApp/app/app.browser.module.ts
         @ ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
         @ multi event-source-polyfill webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=__webpack_hmr&dynamicPublicPath=true ./ClientApp/boot.browser.ts
```

Comment: I don't *think* there is a solution to this. I have come to realize that dgram is part of node and what I am trying to do is run js client-side (in chrome) but the js will only work in a node.js server application.

I thought that webpack would package everything up and make it available client-side, but I guess that's not how it works.